# basic api call function w/ jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, plugins

I'm using the PrettyPhoto jQuery plugin for an image gallery, and I'd like to make an API call with a basic text link using the following function to navigate to the next image in a series:

```
$.prettyPhoto.changePage('next');
```

Since I'll be making this call frequently throughout the site, I'd like to create a basic Javascript function "next" so that for each onclick instance, I can simply write "onclick=next();" rather than typing out the whole thing-- i.e. onClick="$.prettyPhoto.changePage('next');"-- each time. I've tried to write the function as follows, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function next() {
        $.prettyPhoto.changePage('next');
    };
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm obviously a novice at JS programming, but any direction here would be most appreciated; and please let me know if I should provide any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to wrap your function in the document ready. Apart from that, you would be putting  the next function in the global space which is something you should try to avoid. You could do something like:

```
$.nextPhoto = function() { $.prettyPhoto.changePage('next');}
```

and call it with

```
$.nextPhoto();
```

which puts it in the jQuery namespace but the better approach would be to use jquery event handlers `.click()` and bind the prettyPhoto function directly to the links rather than use inline javascript

Comment: thanks much dan-- that works perfectly; and I understand in the abstract what you're saying about binding the function to the links via jq event handlers, but not quite sure about implementation. If it's not too involved, could you provide an example?

Comment: There is some good information on the basics of binding links in the [getting started with jquery guide](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery). for your particular case the click would be something like `$('#mynextlinkid').click(function() { $.prettyPhoto.changePage('next'); return false; });`

Comment: hi Dan-- wondering if I can call on your expertise again: I'm trying to bind the link as you suggested and I can't seem to get it working. I have anchors with ids assigned as "next" and "previous" and calling them via the click function as `$('#next')` and `$('#previous')` I have the script appended to the bottom the page exactly as you have written above-- should I be placing it elsewhere or calling it in a different way?

Comment: It is difficult to see why exactly it is not working for you without seeing all the code. Events should be bound after the document has loaded to ensure the element is available at that point. Surround binding script with a `$('document').ready(function() {..});`. If that does not work then you would probably need to debug using Firebug to see if it is your selector not working or if the code within the click event is not working. Sorry I cannot be more specific.